# Xamarin.Android OnActivityResult not being called inside a Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

It appears as if OnActivityResult does not get called after accepting the picture taken from the camera.

**Am I calling StartActivityForResult() wrong?, or is there something I am missing.**

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var m_View = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Feed, null);

            btnCamera = m_View.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnCamera);
            btnGallery = m_View.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnGallery);

            ivPicture = m_View.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);

            btnCamera.Click += (sender, e) => {
                //launch gallery
                //allow photo editing/saving

                var mediaPicker = new MediaPicker (Activity);
                if (!mediaPicker.IsCameraAvailable){
//                      Console.WriteLine ("No Camera!");
                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                    StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            };

            btnGallery.Click += (sender, e) => {
                //launch gallery
                //allow photo editing/saving
                var imageIntent = new Intent ();
                imageIntent.SetType ("image/*");
                imageIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionGetContent);
                StartActivityForResult (
                    Intent.CreateChooser (imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);

            };

            return m_View;
        }

        protected virtual void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine ("WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
            Uri contentUri = data.Data;
            ivPicture.SetImageURI (data.Data);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. I created a sample and it worked just fine for me. The only difference I see is that it looks like your *override* is not correct. It should be **public override void OnActivityResult()**

```c#
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MainFragment, container, false);
    var button = rootView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_camera);
    button.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    };
    return rootView;
}

public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.Debug("TestFragment", "Got result");

    // do what you want with the result here
}
```

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow. I was having issues when compiling override void, but I will give it another shot. Perhaps I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the *data type* of `resultCode` to `int`, instead of `Result` and making the overridden function `public`.

e.g.

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

For the people that use **Android.Support.V4.App** Fragment. You can override the **OnActivityResult** method in your Fragment **but it will never be called** if you use this in combination with a **FragmentActivity**!
It will be the **OnActivityResult** of the **FragmentActivity** that will be called. This can be implemented like following:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for request code is same as provided for startActivityForResult(intent, 0) here 0 is request code.. eg if you put 999 here insted of 0 ..then in onActivity result method check for requestcode == 999. it is used to check if the intent is the same as asked for and nothing other than that..

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { // ADD THIS
    // Get Data and do something with it 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but i don't believe it is as simple as this. I have tried messing with the codes, but it doesn't ever get to OnActivityResult period. It is something with Xamarin.